# Why does the Software Updater allow me to update the package list without authentication unlike in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates, authentication

I have found recently that when running the Software Updater GUI it automatically, without asking for authentication, updates the local package list, but when running the equivalent in Terminal (`apt-get update`, or `apt update`) I get:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

So how come through the GUI way you can do the equivalent to apt-get update, and have it run without it asking you for authentication, and in Terminal by simply typing the commands, you cannot?

Is it that the two processes are in fact slightly different, and I am misunderstanding something? Or what? How can I sort of simulate this behaviour in Terminal so that I can run the update command without the GUI (or possibly with if absolutely necessary) and without authentication?

Comment: Is it using pkexec and doesn't have to ask or something?

Comment: @Tim: So how would I do the equivalent in Terminal then?

Comment: Run `pkexec apt-get update` maybe.

Comment: @Tim: Nope, that did not work. I need a way to simulating its behaviour in Terminal so that I can run the update command without it and without authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a personal sudoers file:  `sudo -E visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/panda` -- I'm going to assume "panda" is your username. The contents are:

```
panda ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get, /usr/bin/apt
```

Then, you will be able to do `sudo apt-get install whatever` without needing to enter a password.